# How do I connect Azure SQL to my HTML5 web app

Tags: javascript, sql, html, azure

Today I set up a new Azure SQL database and HTML5 Webapp to replace an existing Google Apps Script which wasn't working on iPhones. I have the database connected to the webapp with the connection string, and I want to know how to simply post the details from the html form into the SQL database.

Previously I have been using javascript in GAS with a firebase backend, so I am missing a bit here. Although I can see the connection string in my webapp, I don't know how to then call or post the html form information.

I looks at the functions app method but can't really find the code to post html data, plus how I trigger that from clicking a button on the client side.

I found this code which say it will work, but not to use it because it leaves your database open to hackers.

```
<script>
var objConnection = new ActiveXObject("adodb.connection");
var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=QITBLRQIPL030;database=adventureworks;uid=sa;password=12345";
objConnection.Open(strConn);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM  Person.Address";
rs.Open(strQuery, objConnection);
rs.MoveFirst();
while (!rs.EOF) {
    document.write(rs.fields(0) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    document.write(rs.fields(1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    document.write(rs.fields(2) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    ");
    document.write(rs.fields(3) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    ");
    document.write(rs.fields(4) + "<br/>");
    rs.movenext();
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing to get the SQL database and html5 web app talking?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need some server side code in between I would expect. The browser can then send http requests to the server, which will talk to the database and return the results. Using ActiveX is a terrible idea, since it's not supported any more, most browsers never supported it and it's a security nightmare

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I do this using azure? I had it all working in google apps script and the firebase database. I am guessing it is using the function app httpTrigger, and triggering the script from the button, and adding the javascript into the function. I just can't find anything that looks like what I need to do in any online sample scripts.

Comment: You can do almost anything you like. Write a custom API and host it in an app service, or use azure functions maybe (they should have HTTP endpoints far as I know), or there are other possibilities too

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not connect to any database from an HTML app  which runs on the client side the user will be browsing the site which have a huge security impact. Connecting to a database (it could be sql,mysql or any) happens on the server side, which is where you host your application.

In order to connect to the database you will have to use server side technologies such as node,php or asp.net etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've recreated as a node.js web app. I can write the server side script however the client is not finding it. I will create a new question if I can't figure it out soon.

Comment: You should communicate with the server via the endpoint. Mark if this answer helped

Comment: Do you know how to do that in an Azure Node.Js web app?